# How to properly set MatSort in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material

My mat-table is working all fine, but `MatSort` only works if it's called twice. Here's my code to get the data from API and assign to the `dataSource` variable

```
....
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
....

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getAllDepartments();
}

getAllDepartments(): void {
    this.departmentService.getDepartments().subscribe(
      (data: Department[]) => {
        this.departments = data;
        this.dataSource.data = this.departments;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; // This supposed to be working but I need to call this method one more time for the sort to work properly
        this.isLoading = false;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.openSnackBar(err.error.errors.msg);
      }
    );
  }
```

And I've tried by including `ngAfterViewInit()` too but it only works if I hit a refresh button which refreshes the table data by calling `getAllDepartments()` method. I'm not sure what I've missed here.

Comment: I also use it this way and I have no problem - try moving this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; into ngOnInit (before you call this.getAllDepartments()) - let me know if it works.

Comment: @angularQuestions Doesn't work :(

Comment: Hmm ok the only difference I'll see between your code and mine is this line - could you try changing this: @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

Comment: It was like `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort` before, but then I've read on some post that I should include `{static: false}` if my data is from an API. Either way it didn't work

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry but with only this information I can't help. But if you put your code in a Stackblitz demo, I could take a closer look at it.

Comment: I'll create a simple stackblitz demo and thank you for your effort.